# fill up a square with rectanagles

Tags: integer-programming

I have a square 46*46, I want to fill this up with three types of rectangles of size 29*20, 21*5, 10*4 such that the free space can be minimized? any rectangles can't be overlapped and they can be rotated.

Integer linear programming can be a way out? any idea

Comment: is it allowed to use only one type of rectangle?

Comment: can you use as much rectangles as you want?

Comment: Hi, I have to use all 3 types of rectangles at least once.

Comment: Hi any hints, pls share